# angular compiled html in different languages doesn't call function on scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following scenario:

html:

```
<span ng-if="model.thresholdText" compile="model.thresholdText"></span>
```

compile directive:

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
            element.html(value);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
};
```

`model.theresholdText` contain text sometimes in english and sometimes in japanese/spanish/russian includeing some html. Its always in the format of:

```
some text in origin language 
<a href="" onclick="myFunc()">Origin language text</a>
Some more text in origin language
```

I encounter the following problem: When the origin language is in English, everything works perfectly and `myFunc` gets called. However, when the text is in japanese for example, I get an error in console:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined`

Comment: Have you considered using ngBind instead of your custom directive?  ngBind will populate the contents of a html element.

Comment: i think you need change `onclick="myFunc()"`  to `ng-click="myFunc()"`

Comment: You said `myFunc` gets called and works perfectly, but again you are saying `myFunc` is not defined. Can you show the `myFunc` code?

Comment: @aseferov You are right! In some languages I had onclick instead of ng-click! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of onclick instead of ng-click in the html from server.